# PHP function to remove many addslashes

Tags: php

is there a way or a function to remove many add slashes like below

```
 \\\\\\\"Oracle DBA\\\\\\\"
```

using stripslashes() will remove only one slash,

Do i have to use the preg_replace ? like this

```
preg_replace(/^\\(.*)/,"",$subject);
```

with this work ?

Comment: Your second example is not valid PHP syntax. Missing quotes. And backslashes are string meta characters, needs to be masked twice so PCRE sees it.

Answer (score 2):

If really all you want to do is replace backslashes, then all you need is:

```
$str = "\\\\\\\"Oracle DBA\\\\\\\"";
$str = str_replace("\\", "", $str);
```

If you also want forward slashes removed:

```
$str = str_replace(array("\\", "/"), "", $str);
```

@therefromhere makes a good point though: removing all slashes might break your escaping.

In which case, a negative look-ahead might do the trick:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\\\(?!\")/", "", $str);
```

Should result in `\"Oracle DBA\"

EDIT: Made a woopsie. x2

Comment: micro optimization: a bit neater looking pattern using hard quotes `'/\\\(?!")/'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex expression to do this. Just use this:

```
$string = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), '', $string);
```

Comment: Why would you remove the forward slashes?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many levels of escaping you need to remove you can just run the string through `stripslashes` multiple times.

If you don't then I'm not sure you can do this completely correctly - you could remove all slashes but then obviously you'd break any slashes that were supposed to be there.

Comment: "If violence does not solve the problem, you're not using enough"